# How to ignore trailing white-spaces while making an aggregation query in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an aggregate query to make which buckets the city name of a country. The query (which I make in sense) is as below:

```
GET test/_search
{

  "query" : {
"bool" : {
  "must" : {
    "match" : {
      "name.autocomplete" : {
        "query" : "new yo",
        "type" : "boolean"
      }
    }
  },
  "must_not" : {
    "term" : {
      "source" : "old"
    }
  }
}
  },
  "aggregations" : {
"city_name" : {
  "terms" : {
    "field" : "cityname.raw",
    "min_doc_count" : 1
  },
     "aggregations" : {
      "country_name" : {
        "terms" : {
          "field" : "countryname.raw"
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Now in the documents `New York`occurs two time one with an extra trailing space. The aggregation result which I get is as below:

```
{
     "key": "New York",
     "doc_count": 1,
     "city_name": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
           {
              "key": "United States of America",
              "doc_count": 1
           }
        ]
     }
  },
  {
     "key": "New York ",
     "doc_count": 1,
     "city_name": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
           {
              "key": "United States of America",
              "doc_count": 1
           }
        ]
     }
  }
```

I need the both `New York` to be treated the same. Is there any way I can query that I get both of them in the same group. Any things which trims the trailing spaces will do I guess. Could not find anything though. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way for you to clean this up (i.e. trim) before sending the document to Elasticsearch?

Comment: I know, cleaning can make it right. But I need a solution while querying!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal case is to clean up your fields before indexing your documents. If that's not an option, you can still clean them after the fact using (e.g.) the [update-by-query plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery)...

Or, but that's a **bit worse performance-wise**, use a `terms` aggregation with a `script` instead of a `field`, like this:

```
...
"aggregations" : {
"city_name" : {
  "terms" : {
    "script" : "doc['cityname.raw'].value.trim()",
    "min_doc_count" : 1
  },
     "aggregations" : {
      "country_name" : {
        "terms" : {
          "script" : "doc['countryname.raw'].value.trim()",
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Yet another solution would be to change from `not_analyzed` to an `analyzed` string but create a custom analyzer that preserves the token (as `not_analyzed` does) using the [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) analyzer with a [`trim` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-trim-tokenfilter.html).

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "trimmer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [ "trim" ],
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "cityname": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "trimmer"
        },
        "countryname": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "trimmer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you index `cityname: "New York City "` the token that is going to be stored will be trimmed to `"New York City"`

Comment: the script thing worked perfectly fine. Thanks a lot. And I am going to use the Trim token filter too, that should work.